# Node rest and websockets connection

Tags: node.js, rest, websocket

I created project that contains rest server and `websocket` server every of them works independently on different port. And now i want to perform send message from rest request to all connected websocket clients but i cant figure out "how to implement some `router/middleware` to handle this". Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it alredy. To aquire this i used dependency injection. I created class as middleware to handle messages and used this in rest router:

```
let logicClasInstance = new LogicClassInstance(websockets);
router.get('/accesPage', (req, res) => {
 logicClassInstance.methodToCommunicateWithWebsockets()
 res.sendStatus(200);
}
```

This logicClassInstance can operate on Websocket server and handle messages between both servers. I hope this can help someone.

If this can be made better way I will be gratefull to see some solutions or tips.